# Why does metadata cost double space when creating thin pool?

Tags: linux, lvm, thin-provisioning

### Background

I have a vg with 32G free space on Centos6.9.

When I use `lvcreate -T vg/pool -L 30G --poolmetadatasize 2G` to create a thin pool, it says `insufficient free disk space`.

When I reduce the metadatasize to `512MB`(`lvcreate -T vg/pool -L 30G --poolmetadatasize 512M`), it is created without any error but cost 31G space.

When I use `%` to specify pool's size(`lvcreate -T vg/pool -l 100%FREE --poolmetadatasize 2G`), it is created successfully but pool's size is only 28G, even adding 2G metadatasize, there is 2G free space missing.

### Question

So I have found that poolmetadata will cost double space(specify `512MB`, cost `1G`, specify `1G`, cost `2G`), could someone tell me why it cost double space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you're seeing is the so-called "Spare metadata LV", that gets created automatically when you create the first thinpool in a volume group.

You can double-check this with `lvs -a` to show you all volumes (i.e. also the hidden data/metadata volumes of your thinpool and the spare metadata lv).
If you see any volume called `lvol0_pmspare` or generally something with `_pmspare` as a suffix that's the spare metadata lv.

You can disable its creation using `--poolmetadataspare n` when you create the thinpool, however please have a read of the `lvmthin(7)` manpage before you do so because this volume is required for metadata check and repair operations (i.e. if you don't have it your recovery options are very limited)

Comment: I have done a quick check, it seems true. After checking in detail, I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot.